# Custom notification sound not working in 5.0 and higher

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notification-bar

I am trying to add custom sound to notification. Following is my code:

```
notificationSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.error);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
                            "YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME",
                            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                    channel.setDescription("YOUR_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DISCRIPTION");
                    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                }

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default")
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon
                        .setContentTitle("BATTERY FULL") // title for notification
                        .setContentText("Battery is full. Please plug out the charger. Overcharging may decrease battery life span.")// message for notification
                        .setSound(notificationSoundUri) // set alarm sound for notification
                        .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click

                mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

This code is working in pre-lollipop devices and not on Marshmallow. In Marshmallow, it is using phone's default notification sound. I am assuming this problem is for lollipop and higher devices. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue for a few tries, it looks like NotificationCompat misses a method for sound on between androids 21 and 25, for notification to work you need to set the sound as this

```
val builder: Notification.Builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      Notification.Builder(this, channelId1)
} else {
      Notification.Builder(this)        
}
 ...
val audioAttr = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM).build()
            builder.setSound(
                notification1Sound(), // custom uri
                audioAttr)
```

I don't support versions prior lollipop so this works for me, for older version you might need to add a second version check

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   builder.setSound(
       notification1Sound(),
       audioAttr
    )
} else {
   builder.setSound(notification1Sound(), AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Notification Channel** whit Android O (https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels).
This work only on API 26+ because the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library.

Answer (score 0):

```
 builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle());
```

The full code:

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder =  
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)  
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)  
        .setContentTitle("Notifications Example")  
        .setContentText("This is a test notification");  


Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MenuScreen.class);  

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,   
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  

builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);  
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
builder.setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500);
long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500};
builder.setVibrate(pattern);
builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle());
```

Use these lines of code for custom sound

```
URI uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.FILE_NAME);//Here is FILE_NAME is the name of file that you want to play

builder.setSound(uri);
```

Don't forget to add notification channel

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("XYZ", "ABC",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: This is not working. Was .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()) suppose to fix the problem?